# python error, dont know why

Tags: python, if-statement, mean

implement a program that requests four number (integer or floating-point) from the user. your program should compute the average the first three numbers and compare the average to the fourth. if they are equal, your program should print 'Equal' on the screen.

```
n1= eval(input '[Enter first number: ]')
n2= eval(input '[Enter second number: ]')
n3= eval(input '[Enter third number: ]')
n4= eval(input '[Enter fourth number: ]')
n= ("n1 + n2 + n3 / 3")
     if n== n4:
     print ('equal: ')
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: why are you using `eval` ?

Comment: your code won't work because you wrote `("n1 + n2 + n3 / 3")` instead of `(n1 + n2 + n3) / 3`

Answer (score 1):

Eval in your example is redundant. Solution:

```
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation

def request_number(msg):
    number = None
    while number is None:
        user_input = input(msg)
        try:
            number = Decimal(user_input)
        except InvalidOperation:
            pass
    return number

n1 = request_number('Enter first number: ')
n2 = request_number('Enter second number: ')
n3 = request_number('Enter third number: ')
n4 = request_number('Enter fourth number: ')

if (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3 == n4:
    print('Equal')
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `eval`, take the input and store into variables.

```
n1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
n2 = int(input('Enter second number: '))
n3 = int(input('Enter third number: '))
n4 = int(input('Enter fourth number: '))
```

When it is done, print if average of them equals to n4. pretty simple.

Don't use `" "`, that make it a string as a whole.

```
print 'equal: ' if (n4 == (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3) else 0
```

If want to to do it in your way, fix the indentation. Do it like below:

```
n= (n1 + n2 + n3 / 3) 
# paranthesis isn't needed here, but it's ok to use
if n== n4:
    print ('equal: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
n1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
n2 = int(input('Enter second number: '))
n3 = int(input('Enter third number: ')
n4 = int(input('Enter fourth number: ')

n = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3


if n == n4:
     print('equal: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (Python3):

```
n1 = int(input('[Enter first number: ]'))
n2 = int(input('[Enter second number: ]'))
n3 = int(input('[Enter third number: ]'))
n4 = int(input('[Enter fourth number: ]'))

n = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3

if n == n4:
    print('Equal')
```

If you need floating point values you can use *float* function to cast input values. I believe it's even better to do this than using *int*.